# Wordpress: Display 3 random posts from custom post type every 24hrs

Tags: wordpress, transient

I've seen plenty of articles in and around how to do this but after hours of trying to achieve this using transients, I don't seem to be any closer to the dream!

Essentially I want to use wordpress transients to get 3 random posts and display them in a 'featured' module for 24hrs on my homepage. The 3 posts need to be a mix of native and custom post types.

The code I have so far is:

```
<div class="container">     
<div class="featured-wrapper">
<div class="section-title">featured</div>

<?php          
if ( ( $my_query = get_transient('my_query_cached') ) === false ) :
global $wp_query;
   $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 
   'post_type' => array('post', 'recipe'), 
   'posts_per_page' => 3, 
   'orderby' => 'rand'
   ) 
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
set_transient('my_query_cached', $my_query, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
endif;
?>

<?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="card-wrapper">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <div class="card-img">
      <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"/>
   </div>
   </a>
<div class="card-cut"></div>
<div class="card-content">
   <a href="category.html"><span class="card-category">treats</span></a>
   <h1><a href="recipe.html"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h1>
</div>
</div><!--END card wrapper 1-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div>
<h1>Sorry...</h1>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>   
</div><!-- END featured wrapper-->
```

Currently this code is returning all posts in the database so I believe there's an issue in the first section of this but can't seem to put my finger in it.

Massive thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

Fixed. Code above it actually fine but worth keeping in mind that any edits WON'T show once the page has run once as the transient has already been set. Worth setting the refresh rate to 1 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into one of my sites' frontpage.php and it worked fine straight away. Change your expiry on your transient to 5 or 10 seconds to test it.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I've just tried setting it to 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS) and the articles don't update, they just stick to the same 3.

Comment: FIXED - thank you! I had my tansient set incorrectly in the above comment. I've updated the original question.